# I'm having Flexbox issues?

Tags: html, css

So I am working on a navigation bar for a website and display:flex; won't work. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=REM:wght@300&display=swap');
    </style>
    <title>IDK YET</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li class="list-items">
                <a href="#">Mystery Inc.</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-items">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-items">
                <a href="#">Products</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-items">
                <a href="#">Login</a>
            </li>
            <li class="list-items">
                <a href="#">Search</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is all the HTML there is. I've tried doing other tags, design, and other things and it will not work.

CSS

```
* {
    font-family: 'REM', sans-serif;
}


.navbar {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

The CSS is very basic and is literally just the font with the flexbox instructions. So my main question is if this I have right now, why isn't it converting to a row???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox is working fine, but your `ul` element does not have `display: flex`, only your container element does. This means that the flexbox only contains one element (the `ul`), and the `ul` is still being displayed vertically. Try styling the `ul` instead.

Also, [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) is `row` by default :P

You can set [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-type) to `none` to remove the circular markers from the `li` tags. And, you can use [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) to space it out a bit.

**Example:**

```css
* {
  font-family: 'REM', sans-serif;
}

.navbar-list {
  display: flex;
  /* Styling (not necessary)*/
  list-style-type: none;
  gap: 1rem;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-list">
    <li class="list-items">
      <a href="#">Mystery Inc.</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-items">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-items">
      <a href="#">Products</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-items">
      <a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li class="list-items">
      <a href="#">Search</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```